# contribute to a project with multiple packages

Tags: go

I'm trying to add a fake broker/backend for testing purpose to [machinery](https://github.com/RichardKnop/machinery), which is a task queue library in #golang.

All import paths are absolute in that project,

```
import "github.com/RichardKnop/machinery/v1/..."
```

However, to include my changes, I have to

- manually modify those import paths to my fork

  - *(replace "RichardKnop" with my username),*
- test my changes, and
- revert those import paths to owner's fork before making a pull
  request.

Is there any suggestion on how to contribute others' forks without manually modifying import paths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add another remote to the original git repository. Something like:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/RichardKnop/machinery
git remote add myfork git@github.com:missionliao/machinery.git
git checkout -b master myfork/master
```

Go is just looking for source code in folders so the folder and its actual git location don't have to match.

Comment: Maybe it's a good example why "sub-package" is a bad idea in #golang.

Comment: @mission.liao: what is a "sub-package" and why is it a bad idea in Go? You mean git submodules? (which can be confusing at times, but have nothing to do with Go). Go imports are just directories, it really couldn't be simpler.

Comment: take "machinery" as example, there are "broker", "backend", "config", "signatures" ... sub package under parent package "machinery". All of them are imported by absolute path. And once someone else want to contribute such project, he/she would face the problem I met.